# Increment value of List Object array in Object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, object

I create an object name `month`, List `year` and object `list`. Then I add list `year` to object `list` as keys and add object `month` to list of object `list`.

```
var year = [2021, 2020];
var month = {"jan": 0, "feb": 0, "mar": 0};
var list={};
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    list[year[i]] = [month];
}
list['2021'][0]['feb']+=1;
console.log(list);
```

**Result:** `list={'2021': [{'jan':0, 'feb':0, 'Mar':0}], '2020': [{'jan':0, 'feb':0, 'Mar':0}]}`

Results as I wanted, but problem occurred when I try to increment the value of each month by year.
Example: `list['2021'][0]['feb']+=1;`

**What I want:**  `list={'2021': [{'jan':0, 'feb':1, 'Mar':0}], '2020': [{'jan':0, 'feb':0, 'Mar':0}]}`

**What I get:** `list={'2021': [{'jan':0, 'feb':1, 'Mar':0}], '2020': [{'jan':0, 'feb':1, 'Mar':0}]}`

Comment: Right.  You have one `month` array, and you've just stored two references to that array.  If you do `list[year[i]] = [{"jan": 0, "feb": 0, "mar": 0}];` instead of using `month`, it should work.

Comment: change `list[year[i]] = [month];`to `list[year[i]] = [{...month}];` and it should work (this will basically clone the month into a new object, instead of having the same object in both

Comment: Or move the `var month = {...}` line inside the `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```js
var year = [2021, 2020];
var month = {"jan": 0, "feb": 0, "mar": 0};
var list={};
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    list[year[i]] = [Object.assign({}, month)];
}
list['2021'][0]['feb']+=1;
console.log(list);
```